# How to concatenation an object attributes in js

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I am using an object in javascript  and I need to get it's values by dynamic attributes, how do I use concatenation  to get the **right syntax** ?

To make it clearer this is my code:

```
dataObj[0].xxxxxxxx.Value;(xxxxxxx -> dynamic)
```

I tried: set my attr name in a var :

```
var curr = "games" - > `dataObj[0].+curr+.Value;`    //- NO GOOD
use [] - > `dataObj[0].[curr].Value`                 //- NO GOOD
use +"+ - > `dataObj[0].+'"'+curr+'"'+.Value`        //- NO GOOD
```

Comment: Use second pair of [] without the dot: `dataObj[0][curr].Value`

Comment: @Krypt1 hey please answer so I will mark it as right. thanks :)

Comment: "how do I use concatenation" — You don't!

Comment: @Quentin Why not ?! :- O

Comment: @Damkulul — Because there is no good approach to solving your problem that involves concatenation.